# javascript validation for two different submit buttons

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form as follows:-

```
****<form name = "query" id="myDiv" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "Response.php" onsubmit = "return commentValidationTest()">****
```

Within this form there are two submit buttons

```
<input type="Submit" name ="sub" id ="sub" value="Save" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" >

<input type="Submit" name ="submit" id ="submit" value ="Submit" align = "center" style="width: 80px; float: center;">
```

When both the submit buttons are clicked the validation of the form data is being done in commentValidationTest() which is written in javascript and if the validations are 'Okay', php file 'Response.php' is called.

In my commentValidationTest() I need to detect which of the submit button is clicked, and perform a validation of the form data depending upon the button clicked.

I am doing it like this:

```
var sub = document.getElementById('sub');

if(sub.onclick==true)
{

Validations...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write two functions that returns true or false and call those functions onclientclick attribute.

```
<input type="Submit" name ="sub" id ="sub" onclientclick="return fun1();"
value="Save" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" >



<input type="Submit" name ="submit" id ="submit" onclientclick="return
fun2();"  value ="Submit" align = "center" style="width: 80px; float:
center;">
```

in functions

```
fun1()
{
    check for validations 
    if(validation==success)
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
       return false;
    }
}

same in fun2()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you can write something like

```
<button id="btn1" onclick="commentValidationTest(this)">
<button id="btn2" onclick="commentValidationTest(this)">

function commentValidationTest(el) {
  alert($(el).attr('id')); 
}
```

and then inspect 'this' object that will have clicked button info.

Answer (score 0):

Use This :-

If you are having form this.

```
****<form name = "query" id="myDiv" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "Response.php" >****
```

Having Inputs

```
<input type="Submit" name ="sub" id ="sub" value="Save" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" >

<input type="Submit" name ="submit" id ="submit" value ="Submit" align = "center" style="width: 80px; float: center;">
```

USe this Code :-

```
var buttonpressed; 
$('.classAndDocsFormSubmit').click(function() { 
    buttonpressed = $(this).attr('name') 
});
$('#addClassAndDocs').submit(function() { 
    //alert('button clicked was ' + buttonpressed) 
        if(buttonpressed=="sub") {
      commentValidationTest()

          } else {

          commentValidationTest2()
         }

    return(false) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation with a form that had both register and login functions and handled it this way

```
 <form id="manual_login" >
     <button type="submit" id="loginButton" name="login" value="login">Login</button>
     <button type="submit" id="registerButton" name="register" value="new" align="left">Join</button>
 </form>
```

Get the value of the button so that you know which one was clicked:

```
$('#manual_login button').click(function(event) {
    var test = $(this).data('clicked',$(event.target));
    op = test.val();
});
```

Then do what you need to do based on the button:

```
$('#manual_login').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent the default submit
        if(op == "new"){
            //code here.
            // commentValidationTest()
        } else {    
            var form = $(this).serialize();
            commentValidationTest(form);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around using `onclick` on buttons:

```
<form onsubmit="return doStuff()">
  <input type='submit' name='save' value='Save' onclick='who(this.name);'/>
  <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' onclick='who(this.name);'/>
</form>

<script>
var isSave = false;

var who = function(name) {
  isSave = 'save' === name;
};

var doStuff = function() {
  if(isSave) {
    //
  } else {
    //
  }
  return true; //false, if do not want to submit
};
</script>
```